Confused about the way PySide6-lupdate determines the context for the tr method
While trying to generate ts files with PySide6-lupdate, I found the following situation：
The simplified Python code is as follows
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject

class Foo(QObject):
    def info(self):
        return self.tr('inside')

Bar = Foo()
Bar.tr('outside')

self = Foo()
self.tr('special one')

And this is the corresponding content in .ts file generated by PySide6-lupdate
<context>
    <name>Bar</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="../test.py" line="11"/>
        <source>outside</source>
        <translation type="unfinished"></translation>
    </message>
</context>
<context>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="../test.py" line="8"/>
        <source>inside</source>
        <translation type="unfinished"></translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="../test.py" line="12"/>
        <source>special one</source>
        <translation type="unfinished"></translation>
    </message>
</context>

The context of tr is summarized as follows:

In the class definition, the context is Foo same as the name of the class
For the instance of Foo with the variable name Bar, the context is Bar which is the variable name.
More specifically, for the instance of Foo with the variable name self, the context is Foo again.

I'd like to know why the difference and how to make sure that the context of the tr method is the class name.

Your question is unclear. The context is based on the class, not on the instance, which makes sense: 1. the name of the reference to the instance is irrelevant (there could be no name at all, or the same instance could have multiple references with different names); 2. even if it wasn't the case, Qt has no awareness of Python and so there's no way for it to know how a reference is named).

That is what confuses me. Since the context is related to the class, why does the second string outside get Bar as the context? @musicamante

I'm not sure I'm understanding. Is your question about the actual output of the program (what tr() returns) or the output of lupdate? Because if you're asking about the latter, then consider that it's probably based by simple code analysis, which is not always reliable in automated tools. Besides, at least on PyQt (but, AFAIR, that's also valid in PySide), it's usually better to use QApplication.translate() and explicitly provide the context for each string, because of the way Python works (which is dynamic, while contexts in C++ are retrieved due to static compilation).

My question is about the output of lupdate. So this is because Python is dynamic and lupdate cannot accurately determine the context. And the solution is to provide explicit context through QApplication.translate(). Right? @musicamante

Yes. I cannot find proper docs about PySide, but PyQt ones have an explanation about that. I don't really know how lupdate actually works (also, I normally deal with PyQt5), but it's possible that it just makes attempts to create ts files just based on guesses that parse the sources (and since parsing doesn't consider program logic, it means that's it's not always reliable). In any case, and as far as I know, using QApplication.translate(<context>, <text>) is usually safer, no matter the ts output.

Ok, thank you! Would you mind adding an answer below? Then I can accept it and end this question. @musicamante

I'd prefer not: some aspects I've written above are based on assumptions, I don't normally use PySide, I've had little experience with Qt6 so far, and I also know that some changes related to i18n have been made in all three lately (Qt6, PyQt6 and PySide6), so I cannot provide a reliable answer. My suggestion is to do proper research on your own based on what discussed above, and eventually post your own answer (there's a dedicated button on the bottom of this page) after gathering sufficient data, so that anybody else would eventually find a more reliable answer based on your research.

Finally, I found the reason by reading the source code of lupdate (link). The source code is in C++ and I don’t know much about it, so I can only give a rough explanation.
First, lupdate does not know about the Python runtime. It just guesses the possible context via the Python code.
When guessing the context of tr, the current prefix will first be determined. For example, the prefix of bar.tr is bar. Then it determines the context based on the prefix as follows:

If prefix is empty (e.g. global function), context is defaultContext, which is a empty QByteArray and the corresponding context to it in the generated .ts file is empty too.
If prefix is ​​self, the context is retrieved from the ContextStack, which contains the class name.
In other cases, the context is the prefix.

Back to the situation in the question, in the .ts file:

The context of the string inside is Foo, because tr is in the class and is prefixed with self in Python code.
The context of the string outside is Bar, because tr is prefixed with Bar.
Specifically, the context of the string special one is Foo, because tr is prefixed with self, and ContextStack is not updated in time (ContextStack is processed only if class or def is detected, so the class name is still in ContextStack here)

In the end, the recommended solution is to provide explicit context through QApplication.translate().

try this
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject

class Foo(QObject):
    def info(self):
        return Foo.tr('inside')

Bar = Foo()
Foo.tr('outside')

self = Foo()
Foo.tr('special one')

